# How does Vision control the distance of the beam from the mind stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron, infinity-stones

Superman can control his heat vision, most likely by converging the beams such that they destructively interfere at the intended point of contact.

But what about Vision, how does he control the beam from the mind stone?

*Can* he control it?

Comment: Is there any evidence it doesn't just continue until it hits something?

Comment: fyi: we haven't seen the soul stone yet; vision has the mind stone.

Comment: What if it misses? @OrangeDog

Comment: @Milind same question

Comment: No evidence as such, but newtons law says, a particle continue to stay in motion unless an external force is applied to it! And beams are photons ! @OrangeDog

Comment: @Milind that's not a "but", Newton's 1st law of motion (if applicable) adds further burden on you to justify your question. Subatomic particles don't even follow Newton's laws, least of all photons that (by definition) always travel at relativistic speeds. Who even says the mind bean is composed of photons?

Comment: "Do you know, I don't know what this is. Not really. I know it's not of this world. But it powered Loki's staff, gave you your abilities. But its true nature is a mystery. And yet, it is part of me. ...I wish to understand it. The more I do, the less it controls me. One day, who knows, I may even control it." He can't control it, because he doesn't know _how_ to control it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He can't. The energy beam from his Infinity Stone just goes until it hits something. If he could control his beam the way you're describing, it's unlikely that he would have

> shot James Rhodes out of the sky, nearly killing him

in *Captain America: Civil War*. In that case, Vision's target dodges the beam, and it kept going until it hit the next thing in it's way.

Comment: Exactly what I thought while reading the question